# Find the Product Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find the product number/product name based on the following set of conditions:

1. Select top 1 productnumber in xyz table 
   where product number in (1,2,3) order by filingdate --only if the last filing date has this product number
2. If product number in (4,5,6) for the last filing date nothing should be selected
3. If product number not in (4,5,6) for the last filing, then select the next top 1 productnumber
   where prodcutnumber in (1,2,3) order by filingdate

how can i achieve this in a single query, i tried case statement bu i am stuck with it.

Sample data:

```
pnumber fnumber fdate 
1         1      12/31
2         1       12/10 
1         2       12/10 
4         2       12/11
5         2       12/12
7         3       12/12
1         3       12/11
```

the results should be

```
pnumber fnumber fdate 
1         1      12/31
1         2      12/10 
1         3      12/11
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and some sample data?

Comment: In your data sample also include values that should never show and explain why. "only if the last filing date has this product number " this would be a good example to be placed in your sample set.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving datatype as varchar for fdate.

```
 SELECT id,
   funum,
   fdate
      FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
            OVER(
              partition BY funum
              ORDER BY id) rn,
          *
           FROM   t)p
    WHERE  rn = 1
```